# Slackware 14.2 - black screen after waking from sleep/lock - what process controls sleep/lock?

Tags: lxde, slackware, sleep, lock

I have had Slackware 14.2 32bit installed on a netbook with LXDE as my main DE for about a month now. My main issue is that sometimes the screen is black on waking from sleep [suspend] and the only way to get back to the desktop is to REISUB or sometimes to do a hard reset.

I thought the issue was with LXsession since I am running LXDE, so I updated LXsession to the latest version 0.5.3. However, this has had little effect on improvements. I have done experiments with Xfce, Fluxbox and Blackbox by enabling physlock and then waking, and I still have the same problem: the screen is black on unlock and the only way to get to the desktop is by rebooting. I have tried using the generic kernel instead of huge and it's the same issue. I don't think it's a hardware issue since the netbook was using Debian before and it didn't happen, so it must be something to do with whatever process controls waking from sleep/lock - but I don't know what that is. It could be a graphics issue [it uses Intel 945GME], but I don't think so, I think it's to do with the sleep process. Any help would be great since I am running out of ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be related to an issue with Xfce Power Manager. A sufficient workaround is to suspend via the logout menu in LXDE. The computer then wakes with no issues.